# What is the difference between conditioning on a variable and conditioning on a sigma algebra?

Tags: probability-theory

Question in title.  How are $E(X \mid Y)$ and $E(X \mid \Omega)$ related?  Is there a way of going from one to the other?  How would $\Omega$ be related to $Y$?

Comment: @MANMAID : You have that backwards: Conditioning on a random variable is conditioning on the sigma-algebra that the random variable generates, i.e. the coarsest sigma-algebra with respect to which it is measurable.

Comment: yes that is why I deleted that comment.

Answer (score 4):

$E[X\mid Y]$ is shorthand notation for $E[X\mid \sigma(Y)]$ where $\sigma(Y)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra making $Y$ measurable.

Comment: In that case, if $Y$ and $Z$ are different variables with the same sigma algebra, then $E[X|Y] = E[X|Z]$?

Comment: @keej : Yes. In typical concrete cases that means that if you know $Y$ you can find $Z$ and vice-versa.

Comment: @keej As Michael says. More precisely: if $\sigma(Y)=\sigma(Z)$ then it can be shown that an invertible Borelmeasurable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ exists with $Y=f(Z)$ and of course $Z=f^{-1}(Y)$.